# Adding new list to existing java script object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset, splice

I'm trying to populate the dataset for a barchart. I would like to add 'dataset' to existing barData1 object.

But I'm getting following error. What am I doing wrong here?

> error: jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'splice' of undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsprojStatList = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.projStatList);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var barData1 = {
            labels: ["No. Of Line Items", "Line Items Ordered", "( % )", "Line Items to be Ordered", "( % )", "PO Generated", "PO Approved", "PO Waiting for Approval"]
        };
        //var obj = JSON.parse(barData1);
        //var parse_obj = JSON.parse(barData1);
        var i = 0;
        for (var key in jsprojStatList) {
            if (jsprojStatList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var val = jsprojStatList[key];
                barData1['datasets'].splice(i, 0, {
                    "label": val.BudgetTypeTitle, "backgroundColor": "rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)", "rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)": "#fff"
                    , "data": [val.NoOfBudgetItems, val.NoOfBudgetItemsOrdered, val.NoOfBudgetItemsOrderedPercentage, val.NoOfBudgetItemsToBeOrdered
                        , val.NoOfBudgetItemsToBeOrderedPercentage, val.POGenerated, val.POApproved, (val.POGenerated - val.POApproved)]
                });
                i++;
                };
        };
        //}

        var barOptions1 = {
            responsive: true
        };

        var ctx21 = document.getElementById("barChart1").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(ctx21, { type: 'bar', data: barData1, options: barOptions1 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define `barData1['datasets']` itself as an array before you can add values to it:

```
var barData1 = {
    datasets: [], // populated below
    labels: ["No. Of Line Items", "Line Items Ordered", "( % )", "Line Items to be Ordered", "( % )", "PO Generated", "PO Approved", "PO Waiting for Approval"]
};
```

`.splice()` won't/can't automatically create the array for you with the first use.

---

Side notes:

- Since it doesn't appear you're using `i` for anything else, [`.push(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) can be used in place of `.splice(i, 0, value)`. That'll let you discard `var i = 0` and `i++`.
- If `jsprojStatList` is an `Array` (guessing from `List` in its name), [a `for..in` loop isn't usually appropriate with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).